# VerQueryValue with Unicode UTF-16 (1200) code page string table fails

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, fileversioninfo

I'm trying to retrieve a file description from a PE file using the following code:

```
//This code was simplified &
//most error checks were removed for brevity

BYTE* pData = new BYTE[4096];
LPCTSTR path = L"C:\\Windows\\system32\\Speech\\Engines\\TTS\\MSTTSEngine.dll";
if(::GetFileVersionInfo(path, NULL, 4096, pData))
{
    struct LANGANDCODEPAGE
    {
        WORD wLanguage;
        WORD wCodePage;
    } *lpTranslate = NULL;

    UINT cbTranslate;
    if(VerQueryValue(pData,  L"\\VarFileInfo\\Translation", (LPVOID*)&lpTranslate, &cbTranslate))
    {
        CString strBlock;
        strBlock.Format(L"\\StringFileInfo\\%04x%04x\\FileDescription", 
            lpTranslate[0].wLanguage,
            lpTranslate[0].wCodePage
            );

        UINT dwProdLn = 0;
        VOID* lpBufferName = NULL;
        if(VerQueryValue(pData, strBlock, &lpBufferName, &dwProdLn))
        {
            TRACE(L"Description: %s", lpBufferName);
        }
        else
        {
            TRACE(L"Error=%d", ::GetLastError());
        }
    }

    delete[] pData;
}
```

That specific file ([here's the cop](https://mega.nz/#!2P5D1Iwb!WDMBulOCEvx-yvC0CBRvm4NkaXBmKqfOcFnDxf8dADY)y if you don't have it on your Windows 10) has the string table encoded with `wLanguage` being 0 and `wCodePage` being 1200. In that case `VerQueryValue` fails with error code `ERROR_RESOURCE_TYPE_NOT_FOUND`. But I know that that file has "file description" property when I check it in File Explorer:

[image]

So what am I doing wrong in my code above?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: thank you for locking up this question with that useless answer. That proposed heuristic guessing is not better than just doing this: `for(DWORD langID=0; langID<=0xFFFF; langID++){do_guessing_here();}`. For anyone who wants to see a real solution, there are actually two proposed below. (Another solution, very cool and different one is proposed in the comments to that answer by  RbMm.)

Answer (score 4):

Looking at MSTTSEngine.dll using Resource Hacker, there is an inconsistency in the resource data. Language ID defined by `VarFileInfo\Translation` is `0x0000`, whereas `StringFileInfo` defines `0x0409`. Only the CodePage value matches.

```
BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
{
    BLOCK "040904b0"
    //     ^^^^ -> Problem
    {
        VALUE "CompanyName", "Microsoft Corporation"
        VALUE "FileDescription", "Microsoft TTS Engine (Desktop)"
        // [...]
    }
}

BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
{
    VALUE "Translation", 0x0000 0x04B0
    //                     ^^^^ -> Problem
}
```

So your code tries to read `StringFileInfo\000004B0`, which doesn't exist. 
Unfortunately such cases of broken version resources are not handled well by `VerQueryValue`, because there is no way to enumerate the `StringFileInfo` blocks independently from `VarFileInfo`.

## Solution

There is an alternative way to get version resource information using the [shell property API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/properties/windows-properties-system). I have given an [example in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950848/7571258). On my machine, it correctly reads the file description from MSTTSEngine.dll.

Comment: A [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37953472/7571258), just to link these questions together.

Comment: possible and yourself write small class for parse version resource to tree structure and use - https://pastebin.com/GuHxqa45

Comment: @RbMm: wow, that's a very cool low-level approach. Thanks for sharing! One question though, I'm trying to check your parser code, where did you take that format of the version resource from?

Comment: @c00000fd - this is documented https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/menurc/version-information-structures code is of course working. i only generalize information from msdn. realy if look more close - all items have the common format

Comment: @c00000fd - also this code can be used for modify resourse nodes, and store it via `RsrcNode::Store` and than use in call `UpdateResource`

Comment: @RbMm: yeah, thanks. I can see that. I was also hoping to eliminate those `FindResourceW`, `LoadResource`, `SizeofResource`, and `LockResource` calls and just parse PE structure directly as `RtlImageNtHeader` does. What I'm curious is how to get base-address from `HMODULE` that `LoadLibraryEx` returns? It seems like it generates `HMODULE` by adding 2 bytes to the base-address with `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE` flag and 1 byte with `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` flag. Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: @c00000fd -but `PAGE_ALIGN(hmod)` and is base-address from. [`#define LDR_IS_IMAGEMAPPING(handle)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexa) but however if you parse pe yourself this will be not much more better (if at all) compare `FindResourceW`. the best of course use `LdrFindResource_U / LdrAccessResource` pair. not need separate SizeofResource, and LockResource here

Comment: @RbMm: well, I'm doing it from the user land. So thanks. I missed that macro. I was basically doing this instead `(DWORD_PTR&)lpBaseAddress &= ~0xFFF;` which is the same thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187456/discussion-between-rbmm-and-c00000fd).